# Javascript iframe loading time function for many urls

Tags: php, javascript

Got a very simple function that checks the loading time of an iframe:

```
function loadTime() {
        var beforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime();        
        $('#loading_iframe').one('load', function () {
            var afterLoad = (new Date()).getTime();
            var result = (afterLoad - beforeLoad) / 1000;
            $("#loadingtime").html(result + " sec");
        }); 
    }
```

I load my frame like so (where $url = some link)):

```
<iframe style="visibility:hidden;display:none" id="loading_iframe" src="<?php echo $url;?>"></iframe>
```

After that i put my result into a div:

```
<div id="loadingtime"></div>
```

This works very well for one single url, i want it to work for an array of urls. Heres the structure i would like to have(is this possible?):

```
foreach ($url_array as $i)
  iframe gets loaded with url
    javascript that gets the loadtime of the url
      passint the javascript value to php varriable
        write the php varriable to a database
close foreach and begin the next loop
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, what you would like to do is perfectly possible.

If you are using IDs for the IFrames you should take in account that these IDs should be unique for each iframe, otherwise you will loose the reference to older iframes when you create new ones with the same ID.

You can also create a global `load` event listener and an object that uses the URL as unique key to map data to each IFrame.

To do so create an Object with URL keys and objects as values that store the start-time and the load handler. Each time the global `load` listener is triggered you check if the target is an IFrame, if yes you use its `src` to lookup in that map, get the start-time, calculate the duration which you can store in that object, too.

Good Luck!